# Pasting user input based on current region

Tags: vba, excel

I am working on set of weekly data. Every week, I will add a new set of data to the worksheet. Then, I want to prompt user for input and paste it at the specific column within the current region range. For now, my script will prompt user for input, then finding the last row of the last set of data in the worksheet. Then, i use the current region to activate the first row of the set data. Since the data will be in col E to col O, I want the inputs entered by user to be on col A to col D.

However, when i run my script, it will not paste the user inputs from the first row of the set data and also did not stop on the last row of the set data. Based on the example, I am expecting the output to start from row 388 and last at row 406. The result that i get from my script will paste on row 404 till 811.

For now I just try on one worksheet named "setup" but then i need to modify my script for 20 worksheets with different names.

This is my script:

```
Option Explicit
Public week, datedone, data, location As Variant

Sub pqr()

week = InputBox("Week:")
datedone = InputBox("Date:")
data = InputBox("Data:")
location = InputBox("Location:")

Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long

Set x = ThisWorkbook

For Each ws In x.Worksheets
    If ws.Name = "setup" Then
    LastRow = Cells(Rows.Count, "E").End(xlUp).Row
    ws.Range("E" & LastRow).Activate
    FirstRow = ActiveCell.CurrentRegion.Cells(1, 1).Activate


With ws.Range("A" & LastRow).CurrentRegion
    ws.Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 1), .Cells(LastRow, 1)).Value = week
    ws.Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 2), .Cells(LastRow, 2)).Value = datedone
    ws.Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 3), .Cells(LastRow, 3)).Value = data
    ws.Range(.Cells(FirstRow, 4), .Cells(LastRow, 4)).Value = location
End With

End If

Next

End Sub
```

This is how the data looks like for the previous week (Week12) complete with user input data and current week (Week13) without user input data
[image: 1.]

This is the result that i get from the script
[image: 2.]

This is what i expected to get for the result
[image: 3.]

Comment: Because i was planning to fill in column A:D based on the existence of col E

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try something like this...

```
Dim Rng As Range
Set Rng = ws.Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
Set Rng = Rng.Areas(Rng.Areas.Count).Cells(1)

FirstRow = Rng.Row
If ws.Cells(FirstRow, 1) = "" Then
    LastRow = FirstRow
Else
    LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
End If
ws.Cells(LastRow, 1) = week
ws.Cells(LastRow, 2) = datedone
ws.Cells(LastRow, 3) = Data
ws.Cells(LastRow, 4) = Location
```

**The complete code should look like this...**

```
Public week, datedone, data, location As Variant

Sub pqr()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Workbook
Dim LastRow As Long
Dim FirstRow As Long
Dim Rng As Range

week = InputBox("Week:")
datedone = InputBox("Date:")
data = InputBox("Data:")
location = InputBox("Location:")


Set x = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("setup")

On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = ws.Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
On Error GoTo 0
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Set Rng = Rng.Areas(Rng.Areas.Count).Cells(1)
    FirstRow = Rng.Row
    If ws.Cells(FirstRow, 1) = "" Then
        LastRow = FirstRow
    Else
        LastRow = ws.Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
    ws.Cells(LastRow, 1) = week
    ws.Cells(LastRow, 2) = datedone
    ws.Cells(LastRow, 3) = data
    ws.Cells(LastRow, 4) = location
End If
End Sub
```

**EDIT2:**

```
Public week, datedone, data, location As Variant

Sub pqr()
Dim ws As Worksheet
Dim x As Workbook
Dim FirstRow As Long, LastRow As Long, n As Long

Dim Rng As Range

week = InputBox("Week:")
datedone = InputBox("Date:")
data = InputBox("Data:")
location = InputBox("Location:")


Set x = ThisWorkbook
Set ws = Sheets("setup")

On Error Resume Next
Set Rng = ws.Range("E:E").SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants, 2)
n = Rng.Areas(Rng.Areas.Count).Rows.Count
On Error GoTo 0
If Not Rng Is Nothing Then
    Set Rng = Rng.Areas(Rng.Areas.Count).Cells(1)
    FirstRow = Rng.Row
    LastRow = FirstRow + n - 1
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, 1), ws.Cells(LastRow, 1)) = week
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, 2), ws.Cells(LastRow, 2)) = datedone
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, 3), ws.Cells(LastRow, 3)) = data
    ws.Range(ws.Cells(FirstRow, 4), ws.Cells(LastRow, 4)) = location
End If
End Sub
```

Comment: I tried the script but then it appears Run-time error '91': Object variable or With block variable not set. What is the problem?

Comment: Why are you looping over sheets when you have the condition like If ws.Name = "setup" inside the For loop as that means the code will execute only on sheet called setup?

Comment: I have added the complete code, run this and let me know if that works for you. Notice that the code is finding the first row in the last block assuming column E contains string constants like Field, a, b, c, d....etc as you have shown in the image (but not the strings which are derived by the formulas)

Comment: Hi, the result came out with no error, however,the output only appear on the first line of the set data. Perhaps, do i have to add loop so that the output will paste from the first row till the last row of set data? From the example, the output only appear in line 388.

Comment: That means the output appears in the correct first row i.e. row 388. Next time if you run the code, the code will put the output in row 389. Isn't that what you are trying to achieve?

Comment: No, i was planning to paste the output from row 388 till row 406 as the data for this week is within that range. Therefore, next week, the output should start from row 408 (first row of next data) till the last row of the next set data

Comment: I have added another edited code (Edit2:). See if that does what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: Hi, thanks, its working  and look great. I just have to add for loop to do this  in all other worksheets. Thanks alot!!